# El archivo wp-load.php en mi sitio Wordpress automáticamente se coloca en 0 btytes cada 2-3 minutos

Tags: php, wordpress

Mi sitio comenzó a mostrar **500 internal server error**. Traté de depurar y buscar el problema depurando todas las opciones y encontré que **wp-load.php** quedaba de 0 bytes, luego lo reemplacé con nuevo **wp-load.php**. y mi sitio web funciona bien, Pero a los dos minutos o menos el sitio se vuelve a caer quedando en 0 Bytes **wp-load.php** y así cada 2-3 minutos mi **wp-load.php** se volvía a quedar en 0 bytes al reemplazarlo por uno nuevo. ¿Le ha pasado esto a alguien, de antemano gracias por su valioso tiempo.

Comment: ¿Te han hackeado el WP? Revisa los logs del servidor web por si acaso.

Comment: Parece ser un intento de hackeo, revisa tu functions.php, también prueba usando este sitio https://www.virustotal.com/ debido a la naturaleza del problema no hay una respuesta absoluta, así que mi recomendación seria realizar pruebas con plugins y themas e intentar solucionar los errores que encuentres o en su defecto, hacer una nueva instalación de WP, si no tienes datos que perder, usa una nueva DB